# Rails: Carrierwave recreate versions does not change old images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, rmagick, carrierwave

My Rails app uses carrierwave to manage image uploads. I have a watermark version of the images on my site. Previously I was overlaying an image on them, like so:

```
def watermark
    manipulate! do |img|
        logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/plc-watermark.png").first
        img = img.composite(logo, Magick::SouthEastGravity, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
    end
end
```

Now I'm overlaying text, like so:

```
def watermark
    manipulate! do |img|
        text = Magick::Draw.new
        text.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
        text.pointsize = 12
        text.font = "#{Rails.root}/public/fonts/hn300.ttf"
        text.stroke = 'none'
        text.annotate(img, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Photo © #{model.user.full_name}\nHosted by Placeology.ws\nPlease log in to remove this watermark")
        img
    end
end
```

Now, this works for new images, but when I call recreate_versions! the old photos are not replaced. How can I get this new watermark to replace the old one?

For what it's worth I'm using Fog with Amazon S3 for storage in both development and production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might not be quite the same issue, but for googleability:

We have a random hash in the filename similar to what is described in [this discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/PWb5OYNhiV8/discussion).

When regenerating images, it would generate new images, using a new hash, but it wouldn't update the filename stored in the database, so it would attempt to display images with the old names.

This reproduces the problem:

```
bundle exec rails runner "Foo.find(123).images.each { |img| uploader = img.image; puts %{before: #{img.image.inspect}}; uploader.recreate_versions!; puts %{after: #{img.reload.image.inspect}} }; p Foo.find(123).images"
```

It gives output like

```
before: /uploads/foo_123_6a34e47ef5.JPG
after: /uploads/foo_123_d9a346292d.JPG
[#<Image id: 456, foo_id: 123, image: "foo_123_6a34e47ef5.JPG">]
```

But adding a `img.save!` after recreating versions fixes it:

```
bundle exec rails runner "Foo.find(123).images.each { |img| uploader = img.image; puts %{before: #{img.image.inspect}}; uploader.recreate_versions!; img.save!; puts %{after: #{img.reload.image.inspect}} }; p Foo.find(123).images"
```

With output:

```
before: /uploads/foo_123_6a34e47ef5.JPG
after: /uploads/foo_123_d9a346292d.JPG
[#<Image id: 456, foo_id: 123, image: "foo_123_d9a346292d.JPG">]
```

**Edit:**

Actually, the above worked with files on disk, but not with fog. To make things easy for myself, I ended up just recreating the images and removing the old ones:

```
Image.all.each { |old|
  new = Image.new(foo_id: old.foo_id, image: old.image)
  new.save!
  old.destroy
}
```

Comment: This does correctly identify the problem I had. I ended up figuring a slightly different solution, but this works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had a similar issue. The fix for my issue was making sure that the new file generated had a different unique name.

Comment: Had to do this again, did something like this to regenerate the whole image (including all versions) with Fog (S3): `record.remote_image_url = record.image_url; i.save!`

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `image.cache_stored_file!` before calling `recreate_versions!`

It's weird because the method itself calls that if the file is cached, but for some reason it wasn't working.